# gulp: when i Run any command like ( gulp watch or gulp ) show this err

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});

// Styles Task
// Uglifies
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    console.log('Runs Style');
});

// Watch files
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts','styles']);
```

> assert.js:81   throw new assert.AssertionError({   ^ AssertionError:
>   Task function must be specified
>       at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (D:\mohamed\CS\Third year\Seconed Term\Web
>   Programming\W-P\project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
>       at Gulp.task (D:\mohamed\CS\Third year\Seconed Term\Web Programming\W-P\project\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
>       at Object. (D:\mohamed\CS\Third year\Seconed Term\Web Programming\W-P\project\js\gulpfile.js:22:6)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Comment: post your gulpfile, this looks like it has to do with how your task is set up.

Comment: var gulp = require('gulp'),
 uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
 gulp.src('js/*.js')
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
// Styles Task
// Uglifies
gulp.task('styles', function(){
 console.log('Runs Style');
});

// Watch files 
gulp.task('watch', function(){
 gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts'])
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts','styles']);

Comment: Can you update your question with this, properly formatted please?